# Implement material design in android 5.0 and lower

Tags: android

I want to use Material Design in different devices including(i.e) **Android 5.1** and **Android 4.4.2**.
So, after 5.0 android uses Material by default. But what about other devices?

Where I can get samples of such project? How to implement `Button`, side K and `FAB`. 
Actually, what is the best and common way to implement material? I know that there are some libs to handle my task, but maybe there is the better way.
Please help me to figure out this issue.
Thanks.

Comment: check it out http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html, but simple googling about material would have given you some examples

Answer (score 1):

You have to use AppCompat Library v21 for Material Design in Pre-Lollipop Device.

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html

---

Additional, want to include ActionButton, Collapsible Toolbar, Floating EditText etc. are available with Design Support Library by Android Developers.

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the AppCompact support library for that.

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html