# No resource found that matches the given name: 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'

Tags: java, android, gradle

The project was running fine. I tried to add a fragment and I am getting below error.

> Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
> Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Th\AndroidSdk\build-tools\21.1.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

I didn't change anything.

Gradle:

```
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.app.app"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 21
    multiDexEnabled = true
}
```

Please guide me.
Thanks.

Comment: Did you update Android Studio?

Comment: I have updated long time ago. It's 2.1.1

Comment: Try this: `compileSdkVersion 23`, `buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"`, `targetSdkVersion 23`, `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'`, `compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'`.

Comment: So, by default in new version it uses the API level 23 when you add new activity or fragment.

Comment: If you have updated to 23 then it does.

Comment: How can I set it to 21 again?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCuBL.jpg)

just do as the picture show,it will fix the problems!

Comment: just set the "Compile Sdk Version" to API 23 or upper!

Answer (score 0):

```
targetSdkVersion 21
```

This does not work because API 22 and below does not have material design like API 23+(which you are trying to use according to the error). You have to use AppCompat v21. This question may also help you answer your question: [Implement material design in android 5.0 and lower](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31454286/6296561)